# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'yiiactiveform' when 'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,

Tags: php, yii, active-form

In classic gii-generated php code:

```
$form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'stuff-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>true, ...
```

If I set 'enableAjaxValidation'=>true, this javascript error shows up (and validation doesnt work):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'yiiactiveform'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently the problem was that I have included **my own jquery.js**.

The solution is to add this line in beginning of the layout:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery');
```

related: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/17846-jquery-conflict-ajax-validation-not-working/